# AVD starts every time I run an Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

Every time I run my Android project from Eclipse, it starts a new Android Virtual Device to run it in. How can I make it run in an existing AVD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your Run or Debug configuration (Run => Run Configurations ) and set Target mode manual.

Comment: i restart my computer , the problem gone . it's weird. thanks any way.

Answer (score 1):

create a new AVD manually and also Run your `Android` Project with following steps:

1. Right Click on your **Project**
2. Click on **Run As**
3. Click on **Run Configuration**
4. click on **Target** and select **Manual**.

Select the AVD you just created and click **Apply**.

With this, your application will always ask you before running.

Answer (score 1):

For those who the AVD always restarting (And ADB never find your device online).

1. Close all AVD open
2. Go to your adb folder with  command line (`cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>"` for me)
3. Kill ADB with `adb kill-server`
4. Open an AVD with AVD Manager
5. Wait 5 sec and restart **adb** with command: `adb start-server`
6. Type `adb devices`

Your devices should appear.

Comment: I discovered that I have 3 USB port on my computer. One of them with USB 2.0 and the others with USB 3.0. I do not have any problem now I plug the cable on the USB 2.0 port...

Answer (score 0):

> how can i deal with this?

It can be dealt with in many ways. You don't mention how you expect it to behave.

If an android device is plugged in the usb slot and its version is > `android:minSdkVersion` you have set in your manifest file, the app should automatically run on your device.

if you want to run on an AVD, right click on project -> Run as -> Run configurations ->Target -> Check an already existing AVD. Everytime you run the app, it will load on that AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Delete the AVD
2. Close Eclipse
3. Reopen Eclipse
4. Create new AVD
5. Set newly created AVD to your project's **Run Configuration**
6. **Run** the project